# How to get data from other modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, module

I have a problem with developing sms authentication.

i have a router and controller.
this is my router

```
router.post("/sendsms", smsController.send_post);
router.post("/confirm_sms", smsController.confirm_sms_post);
```

and this is my controller

```
module.exports.send_post = (req, res, next) => {
  const client_phone_number = req.body.phoneNum;
  const client_auth_number = create_auth_num();

  send_message(client_phone_number, client_auth_number);
  res.json(client_auth_number);
};


module.exports.confirm_sms_post = (req, res) => {
  const client_auth_number = req.body.auth;
  const server_auth_number = *; // this point!
  if (client_auth_number === server_auth_number) {
    res.json("OK.");
  } else {
    res.json("False.");
  }
};
```

I would like to use the "server_auth_number" variable in "confirm_sms_post"module as "client_auth_number" in "send_post"module.

But i don't know how.
I tried to solve the problem using the next () method but failed.

any hint would be very appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: Use [a session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) to uniquely identify a requesting device

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'm using JWT certification now, do you make and use the session store?

Comment: Should be easy with JWT. Save the `server_auth_number` in it, then retrieve it from the JWT on the subsequent request.

Comment: @CertainPerformance thank you so much! I don't mean to bother you. that sms authentication is part of the signup process, so there's no jwt issued to the user yet. How can i solve this?

Comment: Issue a JWT earlier - maybe when a unique identity first needs to be saved, perhaps in `confirm_sms_post`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance  You made my day. thank you :)